# webpack Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

When I do a build with systemjs its successful, but when I do with webpack, I get this error..
Error: Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String

Answer (score 9):

Following are my findings after very long Investigation, and many more probably

**First thing to check**

If you are using **ts-loader** you may get

*"No metadata available for the NgModule"*

If its **awesome-typescript-loader** then you will get targeted error result like

- "Final loader didn't return a Buffer or String"*.

What loader you are using the decision is upto to you , I prefer **awesome- typescript-loader**

**Check for the following mishaps..**

1. import statement is pointing to the exact file;
2. typo errors in the file name on import statement; importing the
   modules which are not present.
3. check whether you have installed all
   the loaders like

   ***css-loader node-sass resolve-url-loader sass-loader\
      style-loader url-loader***

4.import statement is empty

ex:

```js
import * from '';
```

5. Services and Providers returning nothing may also cause this error.

Comment: Adding to first answer I also found that with the latest version of awesome-typescript-loader (on windows at least) the webpack entry points are case sensitive.

Comment: As @luke88jones said, my problem was that I was pointing to `import { Time } from './Time';` instead of `import { Time } from './time';`. So what was wrong was having `/Time` when the exact filename was `time.ts`.

Answer (score 3):

After long trial and trial, I changed to `ts-loader`, and the error disappeared.

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts' },
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css'},
      {test: /\.html/, loader: 'html'},
      {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader'},
      // {test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'},
      //{test: /\.(ico|png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=50000'}
    ],
    preLoaders: [
      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'source-map-loader' }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also faced the same issue, i applied all the above mentioned points. However every above answer was unable to resolve the same and then i found that i added a semicolon extra in my code which is causing the error.

***Remove extra semicolon*** after constructor.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(){

    };
}

new MyClass();
```

I removed the semicolon and everything works fine.

```
 class MyClass {
    constructor(){

    }
}

new MyClass();
```